# Is it mandatory to use quotes(single quotes & double quotes) around an index while accessing array elements in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, global

I want authoritative answer for this question or you can say my query.

Let's take a look at following three code snippets :

**First :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <?php
      $x = 5;
      $y = 10;

      function myTest() {
        $GLOBALS['y'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
      }

      myTest();
      echo $y;
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Second :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <?php
      $x = 5;
      $y = 10;

      function myTest() {
        $GLOBALS["y"] = $GLOBALS["x"] + $GLOBALS["y"];
      }

      myTest();
      echo $y;
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Third :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <?php
      $x = 5;
      $y = 10;

      function myTest() {
        $GLOBALS[y] = $GLOBALS[x] + $GLOBALS[y];
      }

      myTest();
      echo $y;
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

For each of the above code snippets I got the same result in my browser **15**.

If you've observed the above three code snippets closely, you will find following three different statements :

```
//From First Code Snippet. Here I've used single quotes around the array index.
$GLOBALS['y'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];

//From Second Code Snippet. Here I've used double quotes around the array index.
$GLOBALS["y"] = $GLOBALS["x"] + $GLOBALS["y"]; 

//From Third Code Snippet. Here I've not used any kind of quotes around the array index.
$GLOBALS[y] = $GLOBALS[x] + $GLOBALS[y];
```

So, my doubts are as follows :

- Is it mandatory to use quotes around the array index while accessing the particular array element?
- If yes then which type of quotes, I mean single quotes or double quotes?
- I've not used any kind of quotes in my last code snippet though I got the same result. Does that mean using quotes while accessing the array elements is not mandatory?
- Or is this the special case which is valid only for `$GLOBALS` array?

Comment: The first two are strings, the last are constants. Normal rules apply. Nothing special here. Just read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) which explains *exactly* what you are looking for. See where it says do's and dont's.

Comment: @JohnConde:Neither I have defined nor used constants anywhere in my code.

Comment: Use single or double quotes. If you don't use either, it will still work in this case, as PHP will search for a defined constant with that name and if it finds nothing, it will fall back to a string. You should get a notice in your error logs, though.

Comment: @user2839497 If you haven;t defined them then that writing your code like that would be incorrect.

Comment: @TomFenech:You are saying in a third case it's falling back to a string. Then how the addition is taking place and I'm getting the same output as of first two code snippets? I should have get some different output since no numeric values are involved in this operation and only strings are involved. Please explain me and clear my doubts.

Comment: @user2839497 **Read the manual**. This site is *not* for tutorials or personal lessons.

Comment: @JohnConde:I know that writing such kind of code is incorrect but why the same output I'm getting even after writing wrong code? That's my question.

Comment: @user2839497 The manual covers that **if you read it**.

Comment: The **array key** is falling back to a string, so it ends up working exactly the same as in the other two cases.

Comment: @TomFenech:Thanks for your help. But if you could have posted this as an answer I could have accepted it.

Comment: @user2839497 SO is not the PHP manual! Just [`RTFM`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php) (BTW: Don't forget to turn on your error reporting: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Additional notes: don't use the `$GLOBALS` superglobal, just declare `global $x` in your functions/methods instead - much less messy. Even better still, don't use globals.

Comment: (Incidentally, I am all in favour of recommending the manual, and there are too many posters on Stack Overflow who refuse to do basic research. I think the OP has considered the matter at hand, and offers a well-formulated question - perhaps I have missed something? The 4 downvotes possibly reflects a certain burn-out to which long-standing contributors are all susceptible - and I include myself in that category! I am therefore upvoting to offset some of this reflexive negativity. /cc @JohnConde).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, both single and double quotes behave almost identically. The only exception is that double quotes allow escaping.

`$GLOBALS["y"]` and `$GLOBALS['y']` is the same in this scenario.

`$GLOBALS[y]` may work, but is problematic. `y` references to a constant variable called `y`. If you don't have one, it is parsed as a string, thus working like like the above.

## Regarding your questions

But it's in fact wrong and you should use quotes!

> Is it mandatory to use quotes around the array index while accessing the particular array element?

Absolutely.

> If yes then which type of quotes, I mean single quotes or double quotes?

Like I said, you can use either. I personally prefer the single (`'`) ones, but that's up to you.

> I've not used any kind of quotes in my last code snippet though I got the same result. Does that mean using quotes while accessing the array elements is not mandatory?

See answer to question #1.

> Or is this the special case which is valid only for $GLOBALS array?

It's rather interpreted as a constant variable defined like `const y = '...';`